# Defining new TYPE for partial function with an implicit parameters

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a new TYPE that would have a pattern of a partial function. Example:

**New Type**:

```
type RouteFunc = (String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) => Unit
```

**Usage**:

def myFunc(str: String, request: HttpServletRequest, response HttpServletResponse)
myFunc("", Any, Any)

For explicitly passed parameters this works really well but I would like to change this type definition so that `HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse` would be passed in implicitly vs. explicitly

**Expected result**:

```
def myFunc(str: String)(implicit request: HttpServletRequest, response HttpServletResponse)
```

I can't find a way how to change the TYPE structure/definition to accomodate the intended pattern, is it possible or is that a language restraint?

**EDIT**:

Usage:

```
object Routes{
    type RouteFunc = (String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) => Unit

    val routes = Map[String, RouteFunc](
        "/data" -> DataSets.dashboard
    )

    def evaluateRoute()(implicit request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) = {
        val path = request.getPathInfo

        val route = routes(path)
        route(path, request, response)
    }
}
object DataSets{
    def dashboard(path: String, request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) = {
        response.setContentType("text/html")
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")

        response.getWriter.write("Hello World")
    }
}
```

I want the `def dashboard` to look like:

```
def dashboard(path: String)(implicit request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse)
```

**EDIT 2**:

At the end I went with passing the parameters explicitly as it's impossible with the current version of Scala as explained by @SergGr and @slouc:

```
import javax.servlet.http.{HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse}
import controllers.data._
import Routes._

class RoutingController() extends JettyHttpServlet {

    type RouteFunc = (String, HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) => Unit
    type HttpRequest = String
    type Path = String

    val routes = Map[(String, HttpRequest), RouteFunc](
        (GET,       "/data")                -> Data.dashboard,
        (GET,       "/assets/*")            -> Assets.getAsset

    )

    override def Get()(implicit request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse): Unit = {
        val path = request.getPathInfo
        val pathTerms = path.split("/")
        val getPaths = routes.filter(_._1._1 == request.getMethod.toUpperCase)

        val filteredList = getPaths.flatMap{
            route =>
                if(route._1._2 == path){
                    Option(route)
                }else {
                    val s = route._1._2.split("/")

                    if(route._1._2.startsWith("/assets")){
                        Option(route)
                    }else
                        None
                }
        }.toSeq

        filteredList.head._2(path, request, response)
    }

}

----------------------

import jetty.Routes
import jetty.Responses._

object Data {

    import javax.servlet.http.{HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse}

    def dashboard(path: String, eq: HttpServletRequest, qw: HttpServletResponse): Unit = {
            implicit val s = eq
            implicit val r = qw
        Ok(Routes.html, views.html.data.dashboard.render("Dashboard").toString())
    }

}
```

Comment: Alex, could you also show an example of intended usage that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: sure, will update with an example

Comment: @SergGr example of current usage added the final output that I need is defined under "I want the def dashboard to look like:"

Comment: Alex, it is still not clear what you are trying to achieve by that `implicit`. If you want avoid passing `request` and `response` to `route(path, request, response)` call, AFAIK you can't do this in today's Scala. If you want to achieve something else, I don't get what exactly.

Comment: @SergGr you understood correctly I am trying to avoid passing the request and response

Comment: Well, I can only re-iterate that this is impossible in current Scala. Moreover I don't understand what is the big deal about it in such a context.

Comment: This was more convenience only, it's not functionaliy required. Alot of methods down the stack already use those parameters implicitly this was the only place that broke the chain so I looked into a implicit based solution. If there is no way to solve this then it's not a problem :) thanks for the help and explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, you want to define a function with implicit parameters. This is not possible. Not only is it a language constraint, it's also a logical one. Functions are a mathematical concept and there's no such thing as "implicit parameters" there. There's no way to provide a subset of parameters, and take the rest "from the scope".

In Scala there's a way to transform a method into a function; the mechanism in question is called eta-expansion. Given some method fooMethod, then a corresponding function fooFunction can be defined as

```
def fooMethod(i: Input): Output
val fooFunction: Input => Output = (i: Input) => fooMethod(i)

// or

def fooMethod(i1: Input1, i2: Input2): Output
val fooFunction: Input1 => Input2 => Output = (i1: Input1) => (i: Input2) => fooMethod(i1, i2)

// or

def fooMethod(): Output
val fooFunction: Unit => Output = () => fooMethod()
```

Compiler will perform eta-expansion automatically if you provide a method where a function is expected. In cases where it doesn't do it automatically, you can do it manually:

```
val fooFunction = fooMethod _
```

But even that trick fails if you introduce implicit parameters, for reasons stated earlier.

Example:

```
trait HttpServletRequest
trait HttpServletResponse

type RouteFunc = String => (HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse) => Unit

implicit val request = new HttpServletRequest {}
implicit val response = new HttpServletResponse {}

def myMethod1(str: String)(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) = println("1")
def myMethod2(str: String)(implicit request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) = println("2")

val myFunc1: RouteFunc = myMethod1 _ // compiles fine
val myFunc2: RouteFunc = myMethod2 _ // nope
```

**EDIT:**

Given your edit, this is how I would do it:

```
trait HttpServletRequest
trait HttpServletResponse

object Routes {

  implicit val request = new HttpServletRequest {}
  implicit val response = new HttpServletResponse {}

  type RouteFunc = String => Unit
  val routes = Map[String, RouteFunc]("/data" -> DataSets.dashboard())
}

object DataSets {

  def dashboard()(implicit request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse): RouteFunc =
    (path: String) => {
      // impl of dashboard, uses request and response
  }
}
```

You define a route as a function `String => Unit`, and you define the dashboard as a method which takes implicit request and response and constructs a route for you.

**EDIT2:**

Looks like support for functions with implicit parameters is coming in one of the future Scala versions. I don't like this and I won't use it, we have too much implicit hell in Scala even without it, but it's good to know about it so that I don't keep claiming it's impossible :)

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative :) I understand that implicit hell is a major problem in Scala but it's all about using a feature in moderation, so I try to stick to basics but only utilise implicit for passing only the most commonly used parameters and that is only if it improves code redability vs just because I can (with great power comes .... - well you know :D )

Comment: Are you sure that the plan with `implicit val`s  `request` and `response` will have the expected semantics? I mean what objects you expect to be passed to `dashboard`? Obviously to work properly `request` and `response` must be different for each call rather than just constants from `Routes`

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying they are generally bad, I also use them. But yes, implicit hell is a real-life situation, and those can be a real pain in the a**. In your case I think it makes sense. 

@SergeGr If this is a question for me, I don't know the exact semantics, but whatever Alex was planning to be passing, he will be passing it in my case too. I just modified the signature by omitting the path and instead returning a function of path to Unit.

Comment: @Alex, in the original question obviously `request` and `response` passed to `dashboard` are parameters that come to `evaluateRoute` i.e. different for each call (and this semantics IMHO is obvious from their names). Unless I'm mistaken in the solution you suggest in your **EDIT:** the parameters passed to new `dashboard` will be fixed to the `implicit val`s defined inside `Routes` i.e. effectively constants which breaks the semanitcs. So why do you think this is a valid solution at all? Do I miss something?

Comment: @SergGr I agree from that point of view. Still, question was "I can't find a way how to change the TYPE structure/definition to accomodate the intended pattern", and I think we resolved that one. Now that the usage and restrictions are clear, it's easy to modify the actual code to suit the problem at hand (which may be different than what's used here as an example).

Comment: @SergGr they would still be passed along from an external resource implicitly so it doesnt break the semantics I wil just have to take the original approach of passing the parameters explicitly

Comment: @Alex, sorry but I don't see how your solution proposed in `EDIT` fixes the actual issue which AFAIU is  that the imaginary `TYPE` should contain a function with implicit parameters **_not applied yet_** and which are to be applied later after the function was gotten out from the `Map`. Moreover I don't see how reasonable changes to that example might be a solution to the real problem (except for returning to what we started from).

Comment: @SergGr I added the example that works for me (it's still crude and needs loads of work) and is executing and compiles you can see that code in the "EDIT 2" section. The main reason why I implemented it that way so that I have all my routes in one place with the references to it's controllers

Comment: Haha :) cmon, you just wanted to know how to add implicit parameters to a function, you found out it's impossible, you played around it a bit, we had a nice chat, case closed. Why are you even editing any more :) @SergGr is unnecessarily keeping the topic open when in fact there's nothing more (on-topic) to be said. We can now proceed the discussion to why you're using text/html or UTF-8, or we can move on with our lives and consider the question resolved. :) To be honest, I think the edits with all the controllers and stuff are just poluting the question for anyone who will come here later.

Comment: @slouc, I agree that we have to disagree. I don't see how your **EDIT** is an answer or any improvement whatsoever but after all I'm not the judge here. The most important thing is that Alex is satisfied.

Comment: @SergGr My answer is "it can't be done", I just modified the signatures in my edit to comply with what was requested in order to show how it could be made to compile. I didn't question the motives and semantics, which, if they are wrong in my edit, then they are wrong in the original question too. I agree that explicit request and response are the correct approach, but the question was how to make things compile for the implicit ones. Alex made the mistake of not using As and Bs instead of request and response, this way he got unnecessary semantics baggage.

Comment: @slouc, the point that I disagree with you is "_I didn't question the motives and semantics, which, if they are wrong in my edit, then they are wrong in the original question too_". AFAICS semantics in your edit is different from the semantics in the original question. In my opinion the original code has correct semantics (pass through an object that comes as a parameter to the caller method) and your suggestion - wrong (pass always the same objects). This is why I call it breaking the semantics. This is not about `A`/`B` vs `Request`/`Response`. The difference still holds for `A`/`B`.

Answer (score -1):

Implicit functions are not supported as of Scala 2.12. It looks like they are [planed](https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/12/07/implicit-function-types.html) for one of the later version when Dotty becomes the official Scala compiler